# Flutter: TextFiled become clear when add new number

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my application i have a text field.I create a TextInputFormatter to add as a `inputFormatters` to my `TextField`:

```
class CurrencyTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else if (newValue.text.compareTo(oldValue.text) != 0) {
      var selectionIndexFromTheRight =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.end;
      final f =
          NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en', decimalDigits: 0, symbol: '');
      var num = int.parse(newValue.text.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), ''));
      final newString = f.format(num).trim();
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: newString.length - selectionIndexFromTheRight),
      );
    } else {
      return newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

everything is ok and when i add a price in TextField, the price is separated with `,` from right to left.

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  controller: amountController,
  inputFormatters: [
              CurrencyTextInputFormatter(),
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15),
  ],
```

In the parent of TextField in initState i initialized text field controller :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    amountController.text =
        commaFormatter.format(widget.provider.totalUnpaidAmount);
  }
```

commaFormatter use `NumberFormat` from intl to add comma between numbers:

```
final commaFormatter = NumberFormat("#,###");
```

The problem is here:

> When number added to textfield by it's controller, when i want to delete this number by softkeyboard delete key, the number is not deleted ?But when i add a a new number, the old number completely deleted !!!!

How can i fix this problem?

I want to when number is added to this textfiled, **Be editable** !!!